# Getting views from ResourceIDs in for loop

Tags: java, android, variable-assignment

Look at the following android code.

```
    iv11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immg11);
    iv12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immg12);
    iv13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immg13);
    iv14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immg14);
    iv15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immg15);
    iv16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immg16);
```

Above `6` `ImageView` variables are assigned `6` images. Actually I have to do this for 36 variables. Is it possible to use somekind of `for` loop to accomplish this kind of assignment?

Comment: You could use a `List` instead of having 36 `ivXX` variables.

Comment: I think you should create ImageView by code. Or instead, and better, use a List ad @juan.facorro said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your all ImageView are in **same layout** then using this code you can get list of ids and ImageViews. If they are not in same layout then you need to use nested loop.

```
ArrayList<ImageView> imageList=new ArrayList<ImageView>();
ArrayList<Integer> idList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
LinearLayout ll;

ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

for(int i=0;i<ll.getChildCount();i++){
        View v=ll.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof ImageView){
            imageList.add((ImageView)v);
            idList.add(v.getId());
        }
 }
```

**UPDATE** In your case as I suggested you should use nested loop like this

```
TableLayout tl;

tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

for(int i=0;i<tl.getChildCount();i++){
    View v=tl.getChildAt(i);
if(v instanceof TableRow){

    for(int j=0;j<v.getChildCount();j++){
      View innerView=v.getChildAt(j);
      if(innerView instanceof ImageView){
        imageList.add((ImageView)innerView);
        idList.add(innerView.getId());
       }
    } 
 }

}
```

Comment: But it is a table layout with 6 rows and 6 col

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like RoboGuice to make your code shorter, but you are not going to get around having to tell Android which view id to map to which object.

https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You could do it for the image value variables (iv##) but you could not do it for the int ids generated by R (R.id.immg##) as they are random hexadecimal that are auto-generated and hence you would anyway have to assign them manually and you can't iterate over them.

To convert string to variable, you just need to use (in this case) Integer.parseInt(string) and depending on what number type you want, it will vary.

Answer (score 0):

code from my project:

```
for( Field f : R.layout.class.getFields() ){
  if( f.getName().startsWith( "image" ) ){
    try{
      IMAGE_MAP.put( f.getName().substring( 4 ).toLowerCase(), f.getInt( null ) );
    }catch( IllegalArgumentException e ){
    }catch( IllegalAccessException e ){}
  }
}
```

Comment: It's important to point out that this code uses reflection, which has a really big impact in performance. Just in case the code that the OP posted is in a location where performance is key.

Comment: you overestimate the reflection costs, especially if it must be called only once for an activity or the whole app